# Mercurial Setup for Lotus Domino Designer 8.5.3

Tags: mercurial, lotus, lotus-domino

Working on getting the Mercurial Source Control installed and working with Lotus Domino Designer 8.5.3.

Been using Declan's powerpoint from Lotusphere 2012 "AD102: Source Control For The IBM Lotus Domino Developer" as a guide.

What I've done so far is:

1. Install 8.5.3 Client and Designer via the CI1LPEN.exe install file
2. Enabled Eclipse plug-in install from designer preferences
3. Did a File, Application, Install of 1.6.0 MercurialEclipse and 1.4.3 Mercurial Binaries from http://cbes.javaforge.com/update
4. Verfied they are installed by going to File, Application, Application Management and seeing them listed
5. Closed Domino designer and client.  Restarted.
6. When I open an application in Designer and alternate click on it's title, the "Team Development" option is not listed.  So not able to "Set Up Source Control for this Application.."

Are there any other prerequesites that need to be installed for this to work, or should I should be selecting different install packages?

Comment: The "Team Development" option should be visible even without any additional installed plugins, as it doesn't need them to work. Do you see the "Source Control" option in Preferences under "Domino Designer"?

Comment: I did not notice that. Checked and under Source Control all 4 of the options are selected.

Comment: Found the problem and it is working for me.

Comment: How to do this in 2018?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and it is working for me.

First thing I needed to do was to install the "Source Code Enablement" from:  http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Source%20Control%20Enablement%20for%20Designer .

The next thing was that I was right clicking on the application name in the Application pane, when I should have been right clicking on the application name in the Navigation pane.

Now see the "Team Development" option.

Have been able to run Mercurial through it paces - commit, branch, merge and etc.

Comment: The "Source Code Enablement" you installed is only meant to be used with Domino Designer 8.5.2. It was a preview of the code that would be included in the 8.5.3 release and now 8.5.3 comes bundled with the same functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on the "Source Code Enablement" part.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in 8.5.3 there is nothing that needs to be installed. HOWEVER, the Team Development menu option only appears if you're in the XPages perspective. It doesn't appear in the Domino Development perspective.